# Energy argument to prove that the solution to a PDE is unique

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

**Background Information:**

From Walter A Strauss Chapter 2.

Imagine an infinite string with constants $\rho$ and $Y$. Then $\rho u_{tt} = T u _{xx}$ for $-\infty < x < \infty$. From physics we know that the kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}m v^2$ which in our case takes the form $KE = \frac{1}{2}\rho \int u_t^{2} dx$. This integral, and the following ones, are evaluated from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. To be sure that the integral converges, we assume that $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ vanish outside an interval $\{|x|\leq R\}$. As mentioned above, $u(x,t)$ [and therefore $u_t(x,t)$] vanish for $|x| > R + ct$. Differentiating the kinetic energy, we can pass the derivatives under the integral sign to get $$\frac{d KE}{dt} = \rho \int u_t u_{tt} dx$$ Then we substitute the PDE $\rho u_{tt} = T u_{xx}$ and integrate by parts to get $$\frac{d KE}{dt} = T\int u_t u_{xx} dx = T u_t u_x - T \int u_{tx} u_x dx$$
The term, $T u_t u_x$ is evaluated at $x = \pm \infty$ and so it vanishes. But the final term is pure derivative since $u_{tx} u_x (\frac{1}{2} u_x^{2})_{t}$. Therefore, $$\frac{d KE}{dt} = -\frac{d}{dt}\int \frac{1}{2} T u_{x}^{2} dx$$
Let $PE = \frac{1}{2}T\int u_{x}^{2}dx$ and let $E = KE + PE$. Then $d KE/dt = - d PE/dt$ or $dE/dt = 0$. Thus $$E = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\rho u_t^{2} + T u_{x}^{2})dx$$
is a constant independent of $t$. This is the law of conservation of energy.

**Question:**

> Let $D$ be the domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Use an energy argument to prove that any solution to 
>   $$\begin{cases}
> \Delta u(x) = f(x) \ \ \ &\text{for} \ x\in D\\
> \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + au(x) = h(x)\ \ \ &\text{for} \ x\in \partial D
> \end{cases}$$
>   is unique, where $f$ is a function defined on $D$, $h$ is a function defined on $\partial D$, and $a$ is a positive constant.

I normally don't post a question without somewhat of an attempt of an solution but I am not sure how to proceed with this. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Based on the comments above I will now attempt a proof.

Attempted proof - Assume that we have two solutions $u_1(x)$ and $u_2(x)$. Let $v(x) = u_1(x) - u_2(x)$. Then we have 
$$\begin{cases}\Delta v(x) = 0 \ \ &\text{for} \ x\in D\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}(x) + a v(x) = 0 \ \ &\text{for} \ x\in \partial D
\end{cases}
$$
So,

\begin{align*}
0 = \int_D v \Delta v dx &= \int_{D} v\cdot div(grad (v))dx\\
&= \int_{\partial D} (v \cdot grad(v))\cdot n dS - \int_{D} grad(v) \cdot grad(v)dx\\
&= \int_{\partial D}v \frac{\partial v}{\partial n}dS - \int_{D} |\nabla v|^2 dx\\
&= -\int_{\partial D}v\alpha v dS - \int_{D} |\nabla v|^2 dx\\
&= -\int_{\partial D}\alpha v^2 dS - \int_{D} |\nabla v|^2 dx\\
&= -\int_{\partial D}\alpha v^2 dS + \int_{\partial D}\alpha v^2 dS\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
So we ended up with $$ 0 = - \int_{\partial D}a v^2 - \int_{D} |\nabla v|^2 dx$$ From this we get that $$\int_{D}|\nabla|^2dx = = - a\int_{\partial D}v^2 dS$$ Now the left-hand side is non-negative and the right-hand side is non-positive, which implies that we must have $\Delta v(x) = 0$ so then $u_1(x) - u_2(x) = 0 \Rightarrow u_1(x) = u_2(x)$.

Not sure if this is right or where to go from here though to conclude that we have a unique solution, one of the commentators below stated to think of positive. Any suggestions on where to go from here are greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the reader, it would be helpful to know what precisely is an "energy argument". I tried googling it, but turned up nothing relevant.

Comment: @AlvinLepik I added a background information section to the question if this does not help at all please let me know

Comment: Hint: look at the homogeneous equations; for each equation multiply by $u$ and integrate (over $D$ and $\partial D$ respectively)

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan Just to clarify, you suggest that I multiply $u$ by $\Delta u(x)$ and integrate over $D$ and $\partial D$, not sure if I understand

Comment: @Winther Following your suggestion I am not sure how one can show that $\Delta v(x) = 0$

Comment: @Winther Can you show me how when $v(x) = u_1(x) - u_2(x)$ then $\Delta v(x) = 0$ I have that in my notes but I don't see how $\Delta v(x) = 0$

Comment: @Winther Oh, so because we assume they are both solutions then subtracting them would be equal to $0$?

Comment: @Winther I tried to start the proof but I am not really sure if my approach is correct, could you take a look?

Comment: Ok, I will re-edit it. When I apply the boundary condition do I just substitute in $\frac{\partial v}{\partial n}  = \alpha v$? Thank you for being so patient with me.

Comment: @Winther Forgot to tag you do I just substitute $\frac{\partial v}{\partial n} = \alpha v$ to apply the boundary condition?

Comment: @Winther I apologize I just haven't solved this type of problem before and I become very uncertain of myself when I am not 100% sure that I am doing the problem correctly.

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan Could you have a look at my attempted proof?

Comment: @Winther I think I see where you going with this from the problem above. Essentially we want to note that we have positivity after applying the bopundary condition and thus we will end up with $0$ at the end which I believe implies $u_1 = u_2$ and thus we have uniqueness

Comment: Well, you are almost there, aren't you? Let's rewrite your equation: $\int_{D} \lvert \nabla v \rvert^2 \, \text{d}x = - a \int_{\partial D} v^2 \, \text{d}S  $. If we assume that $v$ is real-valued, then you should get from this equality that $v$ is constant in $D$ (recall that $a$ is positive). You also get from the above equality that $v$ vanishes almost everywhere on $\partial D$. Combining both observations, you find that $v = 0$ in $D$.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, I updated my proof with your comment, could you just explain how $\int_{D}|\nabla v|^2 dx = - a\int_{\partial D}v^2 dS$. I don't recall that, is that some formula or definition I don't seem to recall.

Comment: @Mike Also, is the proof I made now with the changes you mentioned complete now?

Comment: You tested your equation with $v$ and using integration by parts you ended up with $0 = - \int_{\partial D} a v^2 \, \text{d}S - \int_{D} \lvert \nabla v\rvert^2 \, \text{d}x$. From this equation, you get that $\int_{D} \lvert \nabla v\rvert^2 \, \text{d}x = - a \int_{\partial D} v^2 \, \text{d}S$. Now, the left-hand side is non-negative and the right-hand side is non-positive, which implies... The rest should be easy for you.

Comment: @Mike Right, so are you implying that my proof is still not correct or complete?

Comment: Your proof is not correct. Simply because you show that $0=0$ from which you cannot deduce that $u_1 = u_2$. So forget everything you wrote after my first comment and concentrate on the equation I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: @Mike Ok, but before I deduced that $u_1 = u_2$ everything is fine correct? I am trying to figure out your last comment but I don't know what it implies.

Comment: @Mike Does it imply that $\Delta v(x) = 0 \Rightarrow u_1(x) - u_2(x) = 0 \Rightarrow u_1(x) = u_2(x)$?

Comment: @Winther Could you check my proof now to see if it is correct?

Comment: As I wrote: the left-hand side of $\int_D \lvert \nabla v \rvert^2 \, \text{d}x = - a \int_{\partial D} v^2 \, \text{d}S$ is non-negative and the right-hand side is non-positive. Thus both terms must vanish. So $\int_D \lvert \nabla v \rvert^2 \, \text{d} x = 0$ and since $D$ is connected ($D$ is a domain), we know that $v = c$ in $D$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, $0 = a \int_{\partial D} v^2 \, \text{d} S = a \lvert \partial D \rvert c^2$ and hence $v = c = 0$ in $D$. This, now, implies that $u_1 = u_2$.